# Contour plot of 3D particle position in gnuplot

Tags: 3d, gnuplot, contour

I'm trying to plot 3D data in the form X-,Y- and Z-locations of particles in space. I have lots of particles that I want to represent in the X,Y and X,Z plane in some neat 2D manner. I think the best way to do this is a contour plot. My data has the form of 3 columns, each containing the X,Y or Z position of a particle. As a bonus, I have 3 different types of particles and I was wondering if I could get them in 1 plot in a clean way, if not I can make 3 separate plots but I prefer not to. Also I want to do this using gnuplot since I make my 2D graphs in this as well so the goal is to just run one script and all plots are made. My question is, how do I do this? I read several things about contour plots in gnuplot but they all seem to involve either a function of two variables or some other kind of data and I don't know how to modify the code in a way that I can use it since I'm still pretty new to gnuplot.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `dgrid3d` can make smooth 2D projections out of your particle cloud, and `set contour` draws the contour. Add `unset surface`+`set view map`, and check the demos on http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/contours.html

Comment: I tried exactly this but it gave me really strange results. it plotted some differently colored points in the middle of a very large white screen and that was it, this is why I thought I had to do something else.

Comment: Show us *what* you tried. You can make some dummy data with `splot "+" using (rand(0)):(rand(0)):(rand(0))` or similar, so you don't have to upload your original data.

Comment: I tried it again as you described and it worked! I think I messed up the order of set contour and set view map and such. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The order of settings shouldn't matter in gnuplot. If they do, that's likely a bug. Can you reproduce it?

Comment: Well it's still nog working as I intend and I'm just plotting positions rather than contours atm, since that seems much easier. I only plotted one type of particle and that gave a really neat plot but when I added more particles (making the area of my graph much larger) all I could see were some tiny circles in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

It'd help a lot if you just showed *what* you did. If you want help for free, you should take the risk to embarrass yourself a bit for it!

Anyway:

```
#set view map
#unset surface
set contour
set dgrid3d gauss 0.2, 0.2
set xr [0:1]
splot "+" using (rand(0)):(rand(0)):(1) w l
```

The first two commands switch off the 3D part of the plot, please uncomment. Check `help dgrid3d` to fine tune the gridding.